# For this statement, why could I get the error "[: too many arguments"? I am sure I use the "[ ]" correctly in the shell

Tags: shell, if-statement

here is my code :

```
if [ -e vivado*.backup.log ]; then
    rm vivaod*.backup.log
fi
```

The output message is "[: too many arguments"

More curious, same code below can work perfectly:

```
if [ -e vivado*.backup.jou ]; then
     rm vivado*.backup.jou
fi
```

I tried many times and many solutions, but got same error. 
what should I do now ? thankyou ~

Comment: The `-e` operator takes a single argument but you are using a wildcard (`*`) which presumably expands into multiple filenames. That won't work.  The working version probably matches only a single file.

Comment: Exactly it is. Thankyou very much.